# How to update many fields on a table without using queryBuilder?

Tags: nestjs, query-builder

I want to update many fields of the table "Returns", this method will receive an array of integers representing the ids of Return registers and the value to update this registers

Ej: ( [1,2,3,4], "new Value" )

Normally i use this kind of queries

```
await this.returnRepository.update(id, { shipment_id:'SomeValue' })
```

The problem is that in this particular case i need to update MANY ids and if i give an array of Ids using that syntax doesnt work

For resolve this issue I am using querybuilder with this code

```
await this.returnRepository.createQueryBuilder()
                .update(ReturnEntity).set({ shipment_id: shipmentId })
                .where("return_id IN(:...id)", { id: returnIds })
                .execute()
```

**Questions:**

1.- I know the 2nd form of query have the name QUERY BUILDER, what is the name of the first one? I tried to search 'typeorm query' but doesnt give me much information about it.

2.-It is possible transform this query builder into the first opion? How would it be?

Thank you!

Comment: the first one is called 'repository API' https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From the TypeORM docs for [Repository](https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository):

> `Repository` is just like `EntityManager` but its operations are limited to a concrete entity.

Basically, functions like `save()`, `insert()`, `update()`, `delete()` are provided by the repository class for you to easily **access/update** the entity.
When you use a Repository, the functions are limited to the repository entity.

**Repository vs Query Builder:**

In brief, the `QueryBuilder` API provides you with a chain of powerful methods which can be used to create an advanced `SQL` query while the `Repository` API gives you access to basic functionality which are easier to use.

2. Yes, it is possible to convert your QueryBuilder update query into a Repository one.

For this, you could use the `In` operator provided by TypeORM.
This is how you would do this:

```
import { In } from 'typeorm';

await this.returnRepository.update(
    {id: In([1, 2, 3, 4])},
    {shipment_id:'SomeValue'}
);
```

Here, the `In` operator has been imported from typeorm and takes an array of values.
When you run this, it will generate an SQL query like this (part):

```
SET "shipment_id" = 'SomeValue' WHERE "id" IN (1,2,3,4)
```

It comes under the advanced options. You can read more about the [TypeORM advanced options here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options).

I hope this answers your questions.

**External links**:

- [TypeORM Repository](https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-repository)
- [TypeORM EntityManager](https://typeorm.io/#/working-with-entity-manager)
- [TypeORM Operators](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options)

Comment: Excuse me, and what about doing multiples where in Api repository?
For example 'where tableDate >=FromDate and tableDate <=ToDate

how i can change it? With query selector i know i can add the "addWhere" but dont know who to with the other option
this.xxxRepository.find({
where:{
createDate:MoreThan(FromDate)
createDate:LessThan(ToDate) <--- this i can not do it
}
})
thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `In` operator provided by `typeorm`

```
import { In } from 'typeorm';

await this.returnRepository.update(
    { id: In([1, 2, 3, 4]) },
    { shipment_id:'SomeValue' }
)
```

Comment: DUDE! this is i want to do before. Thank u a lot!